# How to design schema is better , product relation with category

Tags: mongodb

I would like design schema relation between product have a multiple category what is your choice performance ( read , write ) is better.

**Schema 1 :: 2 Collection, reference with category_id array**

```
    Collection Category {  id ,   name }
    Collection Product  {  id ,   name , category_ids: [category_id_1,category_id_2] }
```

**Schema 2 :: 3 Collection, reference with new collection**

```
    Collection Category {  id ,   name }
    Collection Product  {  id ,   name }
    Collection product_category  {  id , product_id, category_id }
```

**Schema 3 :: 2 Collection, reference with embed collection**

```
    Collection Category {  id ,   name }
    Collection Product  {  id ,   name , 
      category_ids: {
          {id, category_id_1}
          {id, category_id_2}
          {id, category_id_3}
      }
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Thumb rule is to denormalize(?) while using MongoDB and maybe NoSQL in general. Hence it's preferable to use two collection if you cannot (or must not) use single collection.

The reasoning behind is that MongoDB does not provide transaction(yet) for good reason of seem less scaling. But it does provide atomic update, hence a single collection is safe for operations.

For that reason option 2 of 3 collection is not a good (read really bad) idea.

Looks like Category data is not as frequently going to change as Product data, so I think first option makes more sense than third option.

One more thing is in first option if you use multi-key indexing on category_ids field, That would be beneficial for faster access. If you use indexing on category_ids on third option that would not be as helpful since indexing on object is not efficient as on an array.

One benefit you have in third option is you can hold some associative data for product for each category_id.

If that is one thing which don't want to lose then you can use an array of object.

**Option 4:**

```
Collection Category {  id ,   name }
Collection Product  {  id ,   name , 
  category_ids: [
      {id : category_id_1, limit : 10}
      {id : category_id_2, limit : 20 }
      {id :category_id_3, limit : 15 }
  ]
}
```

In this case we can associate limit factor for each product association with each category.

But do yourself a favor by avoiding the best practices of RDBMS into NoSql.

Answer (score 0):

if i have a 10,000,000 product records

if i choose your Option 4:

```
    Collection Category {  id ,   name }
    Collection Product  {  id ,   name , 
      category_ids: [
          {id : category_id_1, limit : 10}
          {id : category_id_2, limit : 20 }
          {id :category_id_3, limit : 15 }
      ]
    }
```

**Search a product by category_id**

- i think this choice is read performance is bad
- because mongodb find all documents on "Collection Product" by category_id.

---

if i  choose option 2  , I want search a product_id by category_id

```
    Collection Category {  id ,   name }
    Collection Product  {  id ,   name }
    Collection product_category  {  id , product_id, category_id }
```

- I search a product from "Collection product_category" by category_id.
- I have product id lists
- I get product document on "Collection Product" by product_ids

or this choice is better.

Thanks.

Comment: I disagree with the assumption that read performance would be bad. You can query like db.Product.find({'category_id.id':category_id_2}). If you have proper indexes it would be really fast and does the task in a single query,
 
Why I would avoid option 2 is for the simple reason is from product_category you can neither get  product nor category data so you will have to make multiple call, without transaction this might prove a pain point once the application business gets mature.